# CodeName One Simulator Menu Does Not Work

Tags: java

I have been playing with *Codename One* on Windows 7 NetBeans 8.2 and Java 1.8.0_201.

I created a new project, purchased an Apple Developer account, and was able to write a test app and send it to my phone. That was a couple of days ago. Today the simulator menus no longer work: the Simulate, Skins, and Help menus do nothing when I click on them (however the test app works fine).

I have rebooted Windows, reinstalled Java SE and the CNO plugin and removed all skins from the `.codenameone` folder. I also ran Update Project Libs from the Basics CNO Preferences.

What may have caused this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This turned-out to be a problem at the CodeNameOne website.

It began working after I reported the probelm to CodeNameOne.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and add a date when the problem was fixed.